# How to parse RSS feeds with Spring Integration when pubDate not available?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I run into a problem parsing RSS feeds with spring-integration-feed. I followed the example at
https://spring.io/guides/gs/integration/

My feeds do not include a published date. According to the [RSS specifications](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-specification#hrelementsOfLtitemgt), the dates are not required.

As the pubDate is null, the entry is not added to the queue of SyndEntry. See [FeedEntryMessageSource.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-feed/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/feed/inbound/FeedEntryMessageSource.java#L190)

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FeedEntryMessageSource` uses that to detect new entries, without it, you'd get all the entries on every poll.

The only work-around would be a custom message source - you can invoke it from an inbound channel adapter.

If you have a proposal for another mechanism to detect new posts, feel free to open an improvement [JIRA Issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT).

Comment: Actually we have that one already (https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-1810) and my suggestion there is something like `SyndEntryDateStrategy` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I will try to inherit the published date from the channel, available from the [SyndFeed](https://github.com/ralph-tice/rome/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sun/syndication/feed/synd/SyndFeed.java#L288)